# Desktop installation never gets to the graphical stage with a GMA500

Tags: installation, xorg, intel-graphics, gdm

I am trying to install ubuntu desktop on a hardware-set, which on a similar one, I have successfully installed ubuntu server with no issues.

When booting from Ubuntu Desktop CD it ends up at the `ubuntu@ubuntu $` after failing to display the graphical installation interface.

The graphic card is ***Intel SCG GMA500 Video Controller***

The display is ***5" screen 800*480 LCD***

I am seeing the line *Not using built-in mode "640x480" (no mode of this name)* and wonder where can I define my own custom screen resolution in order to move forward.
And wonder whether this is the only thing I will have to do

Below is the output of the Xorg.0.log file

```
[   333.311] 
X.Org X Server 1.10.1
Release Date: 2011-04-15
[   333.311] X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
[   333.311] Build Operating System: Linux 2.6.24-29-server i686 Ubuntu
[   333.311] Current Operating System: Linux ubuntu 2.6.38-8-generic #42-Ubuntu SMP Mon Apr 11 03:31:50 UTC 2011 i686
[   333.312] Kernel command line: file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu.seed boot=casper initrd=/casper/initrd.lz quiet splash -- maybe-ubiquity
[   333.312] Build Date: 19 April 2011  03:33:17PM
[   333.312] xorg-server 2:1.10.1-1ubuntu1 (For technical support please see http://www.ubuntu.com/support) 
[   333.312] Current version of pixman: 0.20.2
[   333.312]    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
    to make sure that you have the latest version.
[   333.312] Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
    (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
    (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
[   333.313] (==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Wed May 25 03:48:00 2011
[   333.315] (==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
[   333.316] (==) No Layout section.  Using the first Screen section.
[   333.316] (==) No screen section available. Using defaults.
[   333.316] (**) |-->Screen "Default Screen Section" (0)
[   333.316] (**) |   |-->Monitor "<default monitor>"
[   333.317] (==) No monitor specified for screen "Default Screen Section".
    Using a default monitor configuration.
[   333.318] (==) Automatically adding devices
[   333.318] (==) Automatically enabling devices
[   333.318] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic" does not exist.
[   333.318]    Entry deleted from font path.
[   333.318] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/" does not exist.
[   333.318]    Entry deleted from font path.
[   333.318] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/" does not exist.
[   333.318]    Entry deleted from font path.
[   333.319] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi" does not exist.
[   333.319]    Entry deleted from font path.
[   333.319] (WW) The directory "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi" does not exist.
[   333.319]    Entry deleted from font path.
[   333.319] (==) FontPath set to:
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/misc,
    /usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1,
    /var/lib/defoma/x-ttcidfont-conf.d/dirs/TrueType,
    built-ins
[   333.319] (==) ModulePath set to "/usr/lib/xorg/extra-modules,/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
[   333.319] (II) The server relies on udev to provide the list of input devices.
    If no devices become available, reconfigure udev or disable AutoAddDevices.
[   333.319] (II) Loader magic: 0x81ffde0
[   333.319] (II) Module ABI versions:
[   333.319]    X.Org ANSI C Emulation: 0.4
[   333.319]    X.Org Video Driver: 10.0
[   333.319]    X.Org XInput driver : 12.3
[   333.319]    X.Org Server Extension : 5.0
[   333.322] (--) PCI:*(0:0:2:0) 8086:8108:4352:9686 rev 7, Mem @ 0xdff80000/524288, 0xd0000000/134217728, 0xdff60000/131072, I/O @ 0x0000e880/8
[   333.323] (II) Open ACPI successful (/var/run/acpid.socket)
[   333.323] (II) LoadModule: "extmod"
[   333.328] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libextmod.so
[   333.329] (II) Module extmod: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   333.329]    compiled for 1.10.1, module version = 1.0.0
[   333.329]    Module class: X.Org Server Extension
[   333.329]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 5.0
[   333.329] (II) Loading extension MIT-SCREEN-SAVER
[   333.329] (II) Loading extension XFree86-VidModeExtension
[   333.330] (II) Loading extension XFree86-DGA
[   333.330] (II) Loading extension DPMS
[   333.330] (II) Loading extension XVideo
[   333.330] (II) Loading extension XVideo-MotionCompensation
[   333.330] (II) Loading extension X-Resource
[   333.330] (II) LoadModule: "dbe"
[   333.333] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libdbe.so
[   333.333] (II) Module dbe: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   333.333]    compiled for 1.10.1, module version = 1.0.0
[   333.333]    Module class: X.Org Server Extension
[   333.333]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 5.0
[   333.333] (II) Loading extension DOUBLE-BUFFER
[   333.334] (II) LoadModule: "glx"
[   333.336] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libglx.so
[   333.337] (II) Module glx: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   333.337]    compiled for 1.10.1, module version = 1.0.0
[   333.337]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 5.0
[   333.338] (==) AIGLX enabled
[   333.338] (II) Loading extension GLX
[   333.338] (II) LoadModule: "record"
[   333.341] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/librecord.so
[   333.341] (II) Module record: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   333.341]    compiled for 1.10.1, module version = 1.13.0
[   333.341]    Module class: X.Org Server Extension
[   333.341]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 5.0
[   333.341] (II) Loading extension RECORD
[   333.341] (II) LoadModule: "dri"
[   333.344] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libdri.so
[   333.345] (II) Module dri: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   333.346]    compiled for 1.10.1, module version = 1.0.0
[   333.346]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 5.0
[   333.346] (II) Loading extension XFree86-DRI
[   333.346] (II) LoadModule: "dri2"
[   333.349] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libdri2.so
[   333.349] (II) Module dri2: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   333.349]    compiled for 1.10.1, module version = 1.2.0
[   333.349]    ABI class: X.Org Server Extension, version 5.0
[   333.350] (II) Loading extension DRI2
[   333.350] (==) Matched vesa as autoconfigured driver 0
[   333.350] (==) Matched fbdev as autoconfigured driver 1
[   333.350] (==) Assigned the driver to the xf86ConfigLayout
[   333.350] (II) LoadModule: "vesa"
[   333.352] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/vesa_drv.so
[   333.353] (II) Module vesa: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   333.353]    compiled for 1.10.0, module version = 2.3.0
[   333.353]    Module class: X.Org Video Driver
[   333.353]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 10.0
[   333.353] (II) LoadModule: "fbdev"
[   333.355] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/fbdev_drv.so
[   333.355] (II) Module fbdev: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   333.355]    compiled for 1.10.0, module version = 0.4.2
[   333.355]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 10.0
[   333.355] (II) VESA: driver for VESA chipsets: vesa
[   333.356] (II) FBDEV: driver for framebuffer: fbdev
[   333.356] (--) using VT number 8

[   333.378] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/drivers/vesa_drv.so
[   333.378] (WW) Falling back to old probe method for fbdev
[   333.378] (II) Loading sub module "fbdevhw"
[   333.378] (II) LoadModule: "fbdevhw"
[   333.384] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libfbdevhw.so
[   333.384] (II) Module fbdevhw: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   333.384]    compiled for 1.10.1, module version = 0.0.2
[   333.384]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 10.0
[   333.385] (EE) open /dev/fb0: No such file or directory
[   333.385] (II) Loading sub module "vbe"
[   333.385] (II) LoadModule: "vbe"
[   333.388] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libvbe.so
[   333.388] (II) Module vbe: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   333.388]    compiled for 1.10.1, module version = 1.1.0
[   333.388]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 10.0
[   333.389] (II) Loading sub module "int10"
[   333.389] (II) LoadModule: "int10"
[   333.391] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/libint10.so
[   333.392] (II) Module int10: vendor="X.Org Foundation"
[   333.392]    compiled for 1.10.1, module version = 1.0.0
[   333.392]    ABI class: X.Org Video Driver, version 10.0
[   333.392] (II) VESA(0): initializing int10
[   333.401] (II) VESA(0): Bad V_BIOS checksum
[   333.401] (II) VESA(0): Primary V_BIOS segment is: 0xc000
[   333.402] (II) VESA(0): VESA BIOS detected
[   333.402] (II) VESA(0): VESA VBE Version 3.0
[   333.402] (II) VESA(0): VESA VBE Total Mem: 8000 kB
[   333.402] (II) VESA(0): VESA VBE OEM: Intel(r)Poulsbo Graphics Chip Accelerated VGA BIOS
[   333.402] (II) VESA(0): VESA VBE OEM Software Rev: 1.0
[   333.402] (II) VESA(0): VESA VBE OEM Vendor: Intel Corporation
[   333.402] (II) VESA(0): VESA VBE OEM Product: Intel(r)Poulsbo Graphics Controller
[   333.402] (II) VESA(0): VESA VBE OEM Product Rev: Hardware Version 0.0
[   333.449] (II) VESA(0): Creating default Display subsection in Screen section
    "Default Screen Section" for depth/fbbpp 24/32
[   333.449] (==) VESA(0): Depth 24, (--) framebuffer bpp 32
[   333.449] (==) VESA(0): RGB weight 888
[   333.449] (==) VESA(0): Default visual is TrueColor
[   333.449] (==) VESA(0): Using gamma correction (1.0, 1.0, 1.0)
[   333.449] (II) Loading sub module "ddc"
[   333.449] (II) LoadModule: "ddc"
[   333.449] (II) Module "ddc" already built-in
[   333.520] (II) VESA(0): VESA VBE DDC supported
[   333.520] (II) VESA(0): VESA VBE DDC Level none
[   333.520] (II) VESA(0): VESA VBE DDC transfer in appr. 0 sec.
[   333.521] (II) VESA(0): VESA VBE DDC read failed
[   333.522] (II) VESA(0): VESA VBE PanelID read successfully
[   333.522] (II) VESA(0): PanelID returned panel resolution 800x480
[   333.522] (II) VESA(0): Searching for matching VESA mode(s):
[   333.523] Mode: 160 (0x0)
[   333.523]    ModeAttributes: 0x0
[   333.523]    WinAAttributes: 0x0
[   333.523]    WinBAttributes: 0x0
[   333.523]    WinGranularity: 0
[   333.523]    WinSize: 0
[   333.523]    WinASegment: 0x0
[   333.523]    WinBSegment: 0x0
[   333.523]    WinFuncPtr: 0x0
[   333.523]    BytesPerScanline: 0
[   333.523]    XResolution: 0
[   333.523]    YResolution: 0
[   333.523]    XCharSize: 0
[   333.523]    YCharSize: 0
[   333.523]    NumberOfPlanes: 0
[   333.523]    BitsPerPixel: 0
[   333.523]    NumberOfBanks: 0
[   333.523]    MemoryModel: 0
[   333.523]    BankSize: 0
[   333.523]    NumberOfImages: 0
[   333.523]    RedMaskSize: 0
[   333.523]    RedFieldPosition: 0
[   333.523]    GreenMaskSize: 0
[   333.523]    GreenFieldPosition: 0
[   333.523]    BlueMaskSize: 0
[   333.523]    BlueFieldPosition: 0
[   333.523]    RsvdMaskSize: 0
[   333.523]    RsvdFieldPosition: 0
[   333.523]    DirectColorModeInfo: 0
[   333.523]    PhysBasePtr: 0x0
[   333.523]    LinBytesPerScanLine: 0
[   333.523]    BnkNumberOfImagePages: 0
[   333.523]    LinNumberOfImagePages: 0
[   333.523]    LinRedMaskSize: 0
[   333.523]    LinRedFieldPosition: 0
[   333.523]    LinGreenMaskSize: 0
[   333.523]    LinGreenFieldPosition: 0
[   333.523]    LinBlueMaskSize: 0
[   333.524]    LinBlueFieldPosition: 0
[   333.524]    LinRsvdMaskSize: 0
[   333.524]    LinRsvdFieldPosition: 0
[   333.524]    MaxPixelClock: 0
[   333.524] Mode: 161 (0x0)
...
...
...
[   333.582] Mode: 117 (0x0)
[   333.582]    ModeAttributes: 0x0
[   333.582]    WinAAttributes: 0x0
[   333.582]    WinBAttributes: 0x0
[   333.582]    WinGranularity: 0
[   333.582]    WinSize: 0
[   333.582]    WinASegment: 0x0
[   333.582]    WinBSegment: 0x0
[   333.582]    WinFuncPtr: 0x0
[   333.582]    BytesPerScanline: 0
[   333.582]    XResolution: 0
[   333.582]    YResolution: 0
[   333.582]    XCharSize: 0
[   333.582]    YCharSize: 0
[   333.582]    NumberOfPlanes: 0
[   333.582]    BitsPerPixel: 0
[   333.582]    NumberOfBanks: 0
[   333.582]    MemoryModel: 0
[   333.582]    BankSize: 0
[   333.582]    NumberOfImages: 0
[   333.583]    RedMaskSize: 0
[   333.583]    RedFieldPosition: 0
[   333.583]    GreenMaskSize: 0
[   333.583]    GreenFieldPosition: 0
[   333.583]    BlueMaskSize: 0
[   333.583]    BlueFieldPosition: 0
[   333.583]    RsvdMaskSize: 0
[   333.583]    RsvdFieldPosition: 0
[   333.583]    DirectColorModeInfo: 0
[   333.583]    PhysBasePtr: 0x0
[   333.583]    LinBytesPerScanLine: 0
[   333.583]    BnkNumberOfImagePages: 0
[   333.583]    LinNumberOfImagePages: 0
[       333.583]    LinRedMaskSize: 0
[   333.583]    LinRedFieldPosition: 0
[   333.583]    LinGreenMaskSize: 0
[   333.583]    LinGreenFieldPosition: 0
[   333.583]    LinBlueMaskSize: 0
[   333.583]    LinBlueFieldPosition: 0
[   333.583]    LinRsvdMaskSize: 0
[   333.583]    LinRsvdFieldPosition: 0
[   333.583]    MaxPixelClock: 0
[   333.585] Mode: 118 (0x0)
[   333.585]    ModeAttributes: 0x0
[   333.585]    WinAAttributes: 0x0
[   333.585]    WinBAttributes: 0x0
[   333.585]    WinGranularity: 0
[   333.585]    WinSize: 0
[   333.585]    WinASegment: 0x0
[   333.585]    WinBSegment: 0x0
[   333.585]    WinFuncPtr: 0x0
[   333.585]    BytesPerScanline: 0
[   333.585]    XResolution: 0
[   333.585]    YResolution: 0
[   333.585]    XCharSize: 0
[   333.585]    YCharSize: 0
[   333.585]    NumberOfPlanes: 0
[   333.585]    BitsPerPixel: 0
[   333.585]    NumberOfBanks: 0
[   333.585]    MemoryModel: 0
[   333.585]    BankSize: 0
[   333.585]    NumberOfImages: 0
[   333.585]    RedMaskSize: 0
[   333.585]    RedFieldPosition: 0
[   333.585]    GreenMaskSize: 0
[   333.585]    GreenFieldPosition: 0
[   333.585]    BlueMaskSize: 0
[   333.585]    BlueFieldPosition: 0
[   333.585]    RsvdMaskSize: 0
[   333.585]    RsvdFieldPosition: 0
[   333.585]    DirectColorModeInfo: 0
[   333.585]    PhysBasePtr: 0x0
[   333.586]    LinBytesPerScanLine: 0
[   333.586]    BnkNumberOfImagePages: 0
[   333.586]    LinNumberOfImagePages: 0
[   333.586]    LinRedMaskSize: 0
[   333.586]    LinRedFieldPosition: 0
[   333.586]    LinGreenMaskSize: 0
[   333.586]    LinGreenFieldPosition: 0
[   333.586]    LinBlueMaskSize: 0
[   333.586]    LinBlueFieldPosition: 0
[   333.586]    LinRsvdMaskSize: 0
[   333.586]    LinRsvdFieldPosition: 0
[   333.586]    MaxPixelClock: 0
[   333.589] *Mode: 112 (640x480)
[   333.589]    ModeAttributes: 0x9b
[   333.589]    WinAAttributes: 0x7
[   333.589]    WinBAttributes: 0x0
[   333.589]    WinGranularity: 64
[   333.589]    WinSize: 64
[   333.589]    WinASegment: 0xa000
[   333.589]    WinBSegment: 0x0
[   333.589]    WinFuncPtr: 0xc00081fb
[   333.590]    BytesPerScanline: 2560
[   333.590]    XResolution: 640
[   333.590]    YResolution: 480
[   333.590]    XCharSize: 8
[   333.590]    YCharSize: 16
[   333.590]    NumberOfPlanes: 1
[   333.590]    BitsPerPixel: 32
[   333.590]    NumberOfBanks: 1
[   333.590]    MemoryModel: 6
[   333.590]    BankSize: 0
[   333.590]    NumberOfImages: 5
[   333.590]    RedMaskSize: 8
[   333.590]    RedFieldPosition: 16
[   333.590]    GreenMaskSize: 8
[   333.590]    GreenFieldPosition: 8
[   333.590]    BlueMaskSize: 8
[   333.590]    BlueFieldPosition: 0
[   333.590]    RsvdMaskSize: 8
[   333.590]    RsvdFieldPosition: 24
[   333.590]    DirectColorModeInfo: 0
[   333.590]    PhysBasePtr: 0x7f800000
[   333.590]    LinBytesPerScanLine: 2560
[   333.590]    BnkNumberOfImagePages: 5
[   333.590]    LinNumberOfImagePages: 5
[   333.590]    LinRedMaskSize: 8
[   333.590]    LinRedFieldPosition: 16
[   333.590]    LinGreenMaskSize: 8
[   333.590]    LinGreenFieldPosition: 8
[   333.590]    LinBlueMaskSize: 8
[   333.590]    LinBlueFieldPosition: 0
[   333.590]    LinRsvdMaskSize: 8
[   333.590]    LinRsvdFieldPosition: 24
[   333.590]    MaxPixelClock: 230000000
[   333.592] Mode: 114 (0x0)
[   333.592]    ModeAttributes: 0x0
[   333.592]    WinAAttributes: 0x0
[   333.592]    WinBAttributes: 0x0
[   333.592]    WinGranularity: 0
[   333.592]    WinSize: 0
[   333.592]    WinASegment: 0x0
[   333.592]    WinBSegment: 0x0
[   333.592]    WinFuncPtr: 0x0
[   333.592]    BytesPerScanline: 0
[   333.592]    XResolution: 0
[   333.592]    YResolution: 0
[   333.592]    XCharSize: 0
[   333.592]    YCharSize: 0
[   333.592]    NumberOfPlanes: 0
[   333.592]    BitsPerPixel: 0
[   333.592]    NumberOfBanks: 0
[   333.592]    MemoryModel: 0
[   333.592]    BankSize: 0
[   333.592]    NumberOfImages: 0
[   333.592]    RedMaskSize: 0
[   333.592]    RedFieldPosition: 0
[   333.592]    GreenMaskSize: 0
[   333.592]    GreenFieldPosition: 0
[   333.592]    BlueMaskSize: 0
[   333.592]    BlueFieldPosition: 0
[   333.592]    RsvdMaskSize: 0
[   333.592]    RsvdFieldPosition: 0
[   333.592]    DirectColorModeInfo: 0
[   333.592]    PhysBasePtr: 0x0
[   333.592]    LinBytesPerScanLine: 0
[   333.593]    BnkNumberOfImagePages: 0
[   333.593]    LinNumberOfImagePages: 0
[   333.593]    LinRedMaskSize: 0
[   333.593]    LinRedFieldPosition: 0
[   333.593]    LinGreenMaskSize: 0
[   333.593]    LinGreenFieldPosition: 0
[   333.593]    LinBlueMaskSize: 0
[   333.593]    LinBlueFieldPosition: 0
[   333.593]    LinRsvdMaskSize: 0
[   333.593]    LinRsvdFieldPosition: 0
[   333.593]    MaxPixelClock: 0
[   333.594] Mode: 115 (0x0)
[   333.595]    ModeAttributes: 0x0
[   333.595]    WinAAttributes: 0x0
[   333.595]    WinBAttributes: 0x0
[   333.595]    WinGranularity: 0
[   333.595]    WinSize: 0
[   333.595]    WinASegment: 0x0
[   333.595]    WinBSegment: 0x0
[   333.595]    WinFuncPtr: 0x0
[   333.595]    BytesPerScanline: 0
[   333.595]    XResolution: 0
[   333.595]    YResolution: 0
[   333.595]    XCharSize: 0
[   333.595]    YCharSize: 0
[   333.595]    NumberOfPlanes: 0
[   333.595]    BitsPerPixel: 0
[   333.595]    NumberOfBanks: 0
[   333.595]    MemoryModel: 0
[   333.595]    BankSize: 0
[   333.595]    NumberOfImages: 0
[   333.595]    RedMaskSize: 0
[   333.595]    RedFieldPosition: 0
[   333.595]    GreenMaskSize: 0
[   333.595]    GreenFieldPosition: 0
[   333.595]    BlueMaskSize: 0
[   333.595]    BlueFieldPosition: 0
[   333.595]    RsvdMaskSize: 0
[   333.595]    RsvdFieldPosition: 0
[   333.595]    DirectColorModeInfo: 0
[   333.595]    PhysBasePtr: 0x0
[   333.595]    LinBytesPerScanLine: 0
[   333.595]    BnkNumberOfImagePages: 0
[   333.595]    LinNumberOfImagePages: 0
[   333.595]    LinRedMaskSize: 0
[   333.595]    LinRedFieldPosition: 0
[   333.595]    LinGreenMaskSize: 0
[   333.595]    LinGreenFieldPosition: 0
[   333.595]    LinBlueMaskSize: 0
[   333.595]    LinBlueFieldPosition: 0
[   333.595]    LinRsvdMaskSize: 0
[   333.595]    LinRsvdFieldPosition: 0
[   333.595]    MaxPixelClock: 0
[   333.598] Mode: 101 (640x480)
[   333.598]    ModeAttributes: 0x9b
[       333.598]    WinAAttributes: 0x7
[   333.598]    WinBAttributes: 0x0
[   333.598]    WinGranularity: 64
[   333.598]    WinSize: 64
[   333.598]    WinASegment: 0xa000
[   333.598]    WinBSegment: 0x0
[   333.598]    WinFuncPtr: 0xc00081fb
[   333.598]    BytesPerScanline: 640
[   333.598]    XResolution: 640
[   333.598]    YResolution: 480
[   333.598]    XCharSize: 8
[   333.598]    YCharSize: 16
[   333.598]    NumberOfPlanes: 1
[   333.598]    BitsPerPixel: 8
[   333.598]    NumberOfBanks: 1
[   333.598]    MemoryModel: 4
[   333.598]    BankSize: 0
[   333.598]    NumberOfImages: 24
[   333.598]    RedMaskSize: 0
[   333.598]    RedFieldPosition: 0
[   333.598]    GreenMaskSize: 0
[   333.598]    GreenFieldPosition: 0
[   333.598]    BlueMaskSize: 0
[   333.598]    BlueFieldPosition: 0
[   333.598]    RsvdMaskSize: 0
[   333.598]    RsvdFieldPosition: 0
[   333.598]    DirectColorModeInfo: 0
[   333.598]    PhysBasePtr: 0x7f800000
[   333.598]    LinBytesPerScanLine: 640
[   333.598]    BnkNumberOfImagePages: 24
[   333.598]    LinNumberOfImagePages: 24
[   333.598]    LinRedMaskSize: 0
[   333.598]    LinRedFieldPosition: 0
[   333.598]    LinGreenMaskSize: 0
[   333.598]    LinGreenFieldPosition: 0
[   333.598]    LinBlueMaskSize: 0
[   333.598]    LinBlueFieldPosition: 0
[   333.598]    LinRsvdMaskSize: 0
[   333.598]    LinRsvdFieldPosition: 0
[   333.599]    MaxPixelClock: 230000000
[   333.600] Mode: 103 (0x0)
[   333.600]    ModeAttributes: 0x0
[   333.600]    WinAAttributes: 0x0
[   333.600]    WinBAttributes: 0x0
[   333.600]    WinGranularity: 0
[   333.600]    WinSize: 0
[   333.600]    WinASegment: 0x0
[   333.600]    WinBSegment: 0x0
[   333.600]    WinFuncPtr: 0x0
[   333.600]    BytesPerScanline: 0
[   333.600]    XResolution: 0
[   333.600]    YResolution: 0
[   333.600]    XCharSize: 0
[   333.600]    YCharSize: 0
[   333.600]    NumberOfPlanes: 0
[   333.600]    BitsPerPixel: 0
[   333.600]    NumberOfBanks: 0
[   333.600]    MemoryModel: 0
[   333.600]    BankSize: 0
[   333.600]    NumberOfImages: 0
[   333.600]    RedMaskSize: 0
[   333.600]    RedFieldPosition: 0
[   333.600]    GreenMaskSize: 0
[   333.600]    GreenFieldPosition: 0
[   333.600]    BlueMaskSize: 0
[   333.600]    BlueFieldPosition: 0
[   333.600]    RsvdMaskSize: 0
[   333.600]    RsvdFieldPosition: 0
[   333.600]    DirectColorModeInfo: 0
[   333.600]    PhysBasePtr: 0x0
[   333.600]    LinBytesPerScanLine: 0
[   333.600]    BnkNumberOfImagePages: 0
[   333.601]    LinNumberOfImagePages: 0
[   333.601]    LinRedMaskSize: 0
[   333.601]    LinRedFieldPosition: 0
[   333.601]    LinGreenMaskSize: 0
[   333.601]    LinGreenFieldPosition: 0
[   333.601]    LinBlueMaskSize: 0
[   333.601]    LinBlueFieldPosition: 0
[   333.601]    LinRsvdMaskSize: 0
[   333.601]    LinRsvdFieldPosition: 0
[   333.601]    MaxPixelClock: 0
[   333.603] Mode: 111 (640x480)
[   333.604]    ModeAttributes: 0x9b
[   333.604]    WinAAttributes: 0x7
[   333.604]    WinBAttributes: 0x0
[   333.604]    WinGranularity: 64
[   333.604]    WinSize: 64
[   333.604]    WinASegment: 0xa000
[   333.604]    WinBSegment: 0x0
[   333.604]    WinFuncPtr: 0xc00081fb
[   333.604]    BytesPerScanline: 1280
[   333.604]    XResolution: 640
[   333.604]    YResolution: 480
[   333.604]    XCharSize: 8
[   333.604]    YCharSize: 16
[   333.604]    NumberOfPlanes: 1
[   333.604]    BitsPerPixel: 16
[   333.604]    NumberOfBanks: 1
[   333.604]    MemoryModel: 6
[   333.604]    BankSize: 0
[   333.604]    NumberOfImages: 11
[   333.604]    RedMaskSize: 5
[   333.604]    RedFieldPosition: 11
[   333.604]    GreenMaskSize: 6
[   333.604]    GreenFieldPosition: 5
[   333.604]    BlueMaskSize: 5
[   333.604]    BlueFieldPosition: 0
[   333.604]    RsvdMaskSize: 0
[   333.604]    RsvdFieldPosition: 0
[   333.604]    DirectColorModeInfo: 0
[   333.604]    PhysBasePtr: 0x7f800000
[   333.604]    LinBytesPerScanLine: 1280
[   333.604]    BnkNumberOfImagePages: 11
[   333.604]    LinNumberOfImagePages: 11
[   333.604]    LinRedMaskSize: 5
[   333.604]    LinRedFieldPosition: 11
[   333.604]    LinGreenMaskSize: 6
[   333.604]    LinGreenFieldPosition: 5
[   333.604]    LinBlueMaskSize: 5
[   333.604]    LinBlueFieldPosition: 0
[   333.604]    LinRsvdMaskSize: 0
[   333.604]    LinRsvdFieldPosition: 0
[   333.604]    MaxPixelClock: 230000000
[   333.605] 
[   333.605] (II) VESA(0): Total Memory: 125 64KB banks (8000kB)
[   333.605] (II) VESA(0): <default monitor>: Using hsync range of 31.50-29.43 kHz
[   333.605] (II) VESA(0): <default monitor>: Using vrefresh range of 56.00-58.97 Hz
[   333.605] (WW) VESA(0): Unable to estimate virtual size
[   333.605] (II) VESA(0): Not using built-in mode "640x480" (no mode of this name)
[   333.605] (WW) VESA(0): No valid modes left. Trying less strict filter...
[   333.605] (II) VESA(0): <default monitor>: Using hsync range of 31.50-29.43 kHz
[   333.605] (II) VESA(0): <default monitor>: Using vrefresh range of 56.00-58.97 Hz
[   333.605] (WW) VESA(0): Unable to estimate virtual size
[   333.605] (II) VESA(0): Not using built-in mode "640x480" (hsync out of range)
[   333.605] (WW) VESA(0): No valid modes left. Trying aggressive sync range...
[   333.605] (II) VESA(0): <default monitor>: Using hsync range of 31.50-29.43 kHz
[   333.605] (II) VESA(0): <default monitor>: Using vrefresh range of 50.00-58.97 Hz
[   333.605] (WW) VESA(0): Unable to estimate virtual size
[   333.605] (II) VESA(0): Not using built-in mode "640x480" (hsync out of range)
[   333.605] (EE) VESA(0): No valid modes
[   333.606] (II) UnloadModule: "vesa"
[   333.606] (II) Unloading vesa
[   333.606] (II) UnloadModule: "int10"
[   333.606] (II) Unloading int10
[   333.606] (II) UnloadModule: "vbe"
[   333.606] (II) Unloading vbe
[   333.606] (EE) Screen(s) found, but none have a usable configuration.
[   333.606] 
Fatal server error:
[   333.606] no screens found
[   333.606] 
Please consult the The X.Org Foundation support 
     at http://wiki.x.org
 for help. 
[   333.606] Please also check the log file at "/var/log/Xorg.0.log" for additional information.
[   333.606] 
[   333.625]  ddxSigGiveUp: Closing log
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what I have done in order to get it up and running smoothly

I re-installed lucid alternate.

When ubuntu installation was completed, I ran the following on the command line:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gma500/ppa 
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get install poulsbo-config poulsbo-driver-2d poulsbo-driver-3d
```

Reboot the machine and Bang! all is just fine.

Note: remember to perform after a version upgrade the commands in the terminal again to update to the gma500 packages matching your Ubuntu version.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is a variation of @thomas michael wallace reply.

Install via the [Alternate CD](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/ubuntu/alternative-download) since its a text based installer - so no Graphical issues to worry about.

Then, when rebooting, press SHIFT to display your GRUB and choose the Recovery Mode option.

When prompted, choose the "Terminal with Networking" option.

Add the EMGD drivers as per [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/HardwareSupportComponentsVideoCardsPoulsbo):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gma500/emgd 
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install xorg-emgd emgd-dkms
sudo emgd-xorg-conf
```

Reboot and this time hopefully you will have a graphical desktop.

Comment: I have finally got some time today to revisit this issue. tried a variant of your approach (more precisely, the one found at https://launchpad.net/~gma500/+archive/emgd). Yet, screen does not look well, it is dark and not clear. I tried my power with playing in some parameters of the xorg.conf but with no help. my screen is "5 800x480 pixels. I am considering re-installing  9.04, copying the xorg.conf into my desktop, then re-installing 10.04, processing the emgd steps, and then copying the values from the 9.04 xorg.conf to the new one. Hope this will work

Comment: Have you tried to turn up the brightness?  look at the bottom of the linked article - there is a suggestion on something to add to your grub.  Hopefully then you can up the brightness using whatever brightness settings you have on your laptop.

Comment: this isn't a brightness thing at all. Just solved it in another way and posting it in a moment

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that this card is too well supported:

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/HardwareSupportComponentsVideoCardsPoulsbo

However one way forward would be to install using the alternate cd, which doesn't use a graphical installer, and on your first boot (should it fail- I've noticed the livecd is more susceptible to problems than an actual install,) drop into the terminal.

From here you can manually setup x-server, `nano /etc/X11/xorg.conf`, and try configuring your video card (or as the log seems to suggest, your monitor) yourself.

I used to have to do this when Ubuntu had trouble with dual-monitors. You can see if you've got it right by typing X from the terminal, and if you end up with a screen with black and white lines you've got it sorted.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Googling over this, there seemed to be [many issues](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_GMA#Linux) with Linux/Ubuntu and this chipset (Intel SCG GMA500).

The only solution which worked for by far me was to install [JoliOS](http://www.jolicloud.com/download)
Which comes with [drivers for GMA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_GMA#GMA_500_on_Linux) and then, from a terminal, install Ubuntu desktop, and remove the Joli's redundant components

**UPDATE: Older Ubuntu, 9.04 works fine as well out of the box**

Comment: Ubuntu 9.04 is no longer supported - you will never get any further updates etc.  Have you tried any of the other answers?

Comment: @fossfreedom you are 100% right! I cannot even have apt-get update, let alone aptitude safe-upgrade. Other solutions did not work, and the nor the JoliOS way as I could not fine a safe way to remove it   without removing the video drivers along

Comment: sticking with my suggested solution since I'm convinced that is the correct route - are there any errors in the xorg log file AFTER the ppa has been added?